# Publishing to all connected clients - Meteor Server Crashing

Tags: mongodb, meteor, websocket, ddp

I'm creating a multiplayer wheel of fortune game using Meteor. I'm very new to Meteor and I feel that the way I've constructed this is terrible... My computer starts sounding like it getting ready for liftoff and then my server crashes eventually :|

I have code that runs a timer on my server that is broadcasted/published continually to all connected clients. Right now I have it set up so my server is doing massive writes to a MongoDB document (Every 51ms). I am then publishing the MongoDB document and having all the clients subscribe to it so they all see the same timer.

On the Client i'm also using Meteor's built-in 'observeChanges' to check for when the timer hits 0.00 and am then invoking a function to spin the wheel.

All of this just seems like a ridiculous way of doing it and it's killing my CPU. What is the best to set up an Meteor app that is able to broadcast/publish the same data across all connect browsers.

The Game works like this... There's a 30 second timer which goes down to 0.00 and then calls a function to spin the Wheel of Fortune.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You do it all wrong, you should not run a timer on server to change Mongo record constantly, do the timer client side, just give them the start signal, or sync them in some other way, but do not use database and publication for this manner, it is a terrible idea to do it this way.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you have an example of how you would give them a start signal or sync them?

Comment: I think as a temporary solution you can use publication as a start signal, for a limited number of clients. I don't have specific solution but I think there must be better solutions out there. So keep searching, or ask more specific questions.

Comment: You should check Meteor forum too, Meteor folks are more active there.